# Windows Servis app does not recognize Smart Card on RDP session

Tags: java, windows, smartcard, rdp

I have java application which is reads token for digital sign and signing data.

If run the application foreground on CMD it is working without any issue.
with this command "c:\java -jar foo.jar"

But when I start it as windows service in background it does not recognize the token.This problem happens only in RDP session.
Also I have no problem on local computer it is working as windows service without any issue.

My question is ;
Is windows has access permission to use driver(token) in RDP session? when the application starts in background as windows service.

Best Regars ...

Comment: Windows service can access only smart-cards connected directly to server. Check out this [aticle](https://superuser.com/q/543490/836164)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Services can access only Smart-cards connected directly to server.

RDP Smart-card redirection mechanism in this case is not applicable because of absence of RDP session.

Check out this [article](https://superuser.com/q/543490/836164)